# AngularJs videoplaylist directive onended event not fired

Tags: events, angularjs, video

I am trying to implement a video playlist that autoplays and loops through an array of given videos.

So far I can not get the HTML5 video to fire the onended event and I can not figure out why

```
app.directive("videoqueue", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        console.log("asdasd")


        if (currentData === undefined
            || currentData.media === undefined) {
            return "";
        }

        var video = currentData.media.videos[0];

        console.log(video)


        var html = '<video id="video" height="1024" width="1280"  controls autoplay>'
            + ' <source src='
            + '"' + 'data/videos/' + video.filename + '"'
            + ' type="video/webm"' +
            ' onended="alert(\'test\')"' +
            '></video>';

        return html;

    }
}})
```

HTML:

```
<videoqueue></videoqueue>
```

Result:

```
<video id="video" height="1024" width="1280" controls="" autoplay=""> <source src="data/videos/sample1" type="video/webm" onended="alert('test')"></video>
```

The video gets played but no alert is shown after it has ended. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onended` event need to be on the `<video>` element not the `<source>`.

```
var html = '<video id="video" height="1024" width="1280"  controls autoplay onended="alert(\'test\')">'
            + ' <source src='
            + '"' + 'data/videos/' + video.filename + '"'
            + ' type="video/webm"' +
            '></video>';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TzW5/2/)